# Securing open access point

Tags: networking, security, wifi

I need to have multiple yet unknown devices to connect to an open wireless AP. I plug various mesurement instruments on this wireless network

I also have an existing network with multiple desktops (corporate network). This network is plugged to the internet

I want to be able to access the wireless network from within my corporate network so that I can work with the instruments from inside my network.

My corporate network is 192.168.0.1 and my wireless network is 192.168.10.1

My instruments have 192.168.10.1-255 and my desktop computers have 192.168.0.1-255.

I only have two cheap routers right now, DIR628 or something like that from dlink.

The problem I have is that regardless of how I wire everything, the wireless network will always have access to the internet so anyone can connect and abuse our tubes.

I maximise security while having an open AP, is this something doable?

EDIT :

I'd like to keep this network open since I don't have a wired connection to the devices. If I screw up the wireless encryption, I have to send the box back to the manufacturer for a hard reset.

Comment: Why do you need it to be Open?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your options as I see it are put the wireless on a separate VLAN and filter that so it doesn't have internet access or to re-think your assumptions. Frankly if it was my network I'd be every bit as worried about people having open access to my LAN as I would be about them having access to my Internet connection, but that's just me.